# In perl, how can I use regex on a hash containing regexes?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a hash in perl which helps me to process regex changes in long texts (written in Latex):

```
my %replace = (
    qr/\\terme\{(.*?)\}/ => '"<term> $1 </term>"',
    qr/\\emph\{(.*?)\}/ => '"<emph> $1 </emph>"',
    qr/\\textit\{(.*?)\}/ => '"<i> $1 </i>"',
);

my $text;

foreach my $pattern (keys %replace) {
       $text =~ s/$pattern/$replace{$pattern}/eeg;
```

Now I want to do the reverse operation and encode back the text into the orignal. So I need to invert the hash, so that it reads:

```
my %invert_replace = (
    qr/<term> (.*?) <\/term>/ => '"\terme{$1}"',
    qr/<emph> (.*?) <\/emph>/ => '"\emph{$1}"',
    qr/<i> (.*?) <\/i>/ => '"\textit($1)"'
);
```

I don't want to do that by hand as I will have tens of commands like this one to invert.

I don't have any trouble finding the right regexes to do the inversion, but my problem is more basic: how to convert the full hash into a text with each item being a line that I can regex? I especially have problems with qr/xxx/ expressions to be treated as plain text.

I did try first to invert the hash, but I got trouble with the qr/xxx/ expressions when I tried to enclose them into quotes.

```
sub invert_simple_dict {
    my (%dict) = @_;
    my %invertdict = ();
    foreach my $key (keys %dict) {
        $invertdict{"qr/$dict{$key}/"}="\'$key\'";
    }
    return (%invertdict);
}
```

A key like:

```
$key= qr/abc/
```

Became in the inverted hash (as printed in Windows shell):

```
'(?^:abc)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I especially have problems with qr/xxx/ expressions to be treated as plain text.

The [re pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/re) has a [regexp_pattern()](https://perldoc.perl.org/re#regexp_pattern($ref)) utility for this

> If the argument is a compiled regular expression as returned by `qr//`, then this function returns the pattern.

More precisely, it returns the pattern and the modifiers

```
use re (regexp_pattern);

my $re = qr/^te.t/im;

my ($patt, $mods) = regexp_pattern($re);

say for $patt, $mods;
```

This prints

```
^te.t
umi
```

So this allows you to extract from the `qr` object `qr/\\terme\{(.*?)\}/` the pattern itself, `\\terme\{(.*?)\}` (along with modifiers).

Then you can edit the pattern as needed, and rebuild a regex.

In my reading this was the question, of how to get the pattern from the object, and not how to write the regex to modify those patterns.  Please let me know if I misunderstood that

---

*Aggregation of some comments follows, regarding objects-vs-strings and "stringification."*

Many operations specifically need a string(s), so expressly not an object (or a number, for that matter) -- like `print`-ing, adding a hash key (which *must* be a string), concatenating (joining) with another string, passing to functions that need a string, etc.

When an object is used where a string is needed it must be "*stringified*."  If its class doesn't define how that "stringification" is to be done then perl (the interpreter that runs the program) does it, and the best it can do is something like `Class::Name=HASH(0x5620b71824d8)`. An object in Perl is a reference,<sup>†</sup> and normally a hash reference thus `HASH(address)`, and for good measure the class name is added to this string.

Establised libraries normally take care of that, defining informative/useful stringifications.  For a `qr` object the stringification produces a valid pattern. (To try: define a `qr` pattern, print it to a console as such, then copy that and paste it in a regex as a pattern -- and it will do the same as the oriiginal `qr` pattern.)

When printing it to console we see what its stringification is: `(?^:pattern-itself)`. This `(?^:...)` is a [particular "*extended pattern*"](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#(?%5Ealuimnsx:pattern)); search for "*stringification of compiled regular expressions*" in the linked section.

In this case though, the `regexp_pattern()` needs *a `qr` object and not its stringification*.

---

<sup>†</sup>  Now as we are getting a [class](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlclass) keyword (feature) this won't be so clear under that keyword.  (The `bless`-based native OO system remains as well.) The idea is that one need not know anything about the implementation and so in fact one doesn't as this is opaque. (Printing out an object gives `Class::Name=OBJECT(address)`.)

Comment: @Henri_S Great :)  Let me know if questions come up, or if more detail is needed/helpful

Comment: Hello Zdim, when I use the regexp_pattern () function over the keys of my hash, it does not work: ```for my $key (keys %replace) {
    my ($patt, $mods) = regexp_pattern($key);
    print "$patt\n";}```

Comment: Hello @Henri_S -- the function `regexp_pattern()` needs a regular-expression-pattern as an object created by `qr`.  See documentation that I link to in the beginning of the answer, it says: "_If the argument is a compiled regular expression as returned by `qr//`, then this function returns the pattern._"   When you send it a key, like in the example in your comment, that's just a string and `regexp_pattern()` can't do its thing with just a string.

Comment: @Henri_S I'm guessing now -- if by any chance you created those keys using `qr` then that won't work: keys in a hash have to be strings so if we assign an object for a key it is "stringified" (converted to a string, what usually makes it useless)

Comment: @Henri_S  I push it too far in my previous comment with "_usually makes it useless_" -- a class can define a "strigification" routine, by overriding the `"` (double quote).  Large librarires may even have distinct methods: for instance  `DateTime` has `DateTime::set_formatter()`, which takes `DateTime::Format::Strptime` object that sets how to turn an object into a string.  But, the point is, it won't be an object anymore -- while `qr` stringifies nicely (print a `qr` object to see what string it produces) it just isn't a `qr` _object_ anymore and so `regexp_pattern()` cannot work with it

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Actually you made me realize that (?^:pattern) expressions were strings I could regex directly. I didn't understand the meaning of the first characters, thought it was hinting that this was an object, not a string. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Henri_S  Two things.  1) When an object is used where a string is needed (printed, assigned to a hash key, etc) if its class doesn't define how a "stringification" is to be done then perl (the interpreter that runs the program) does it, and the best it can do is to produce something like a string `Class Name=HASH(0x5620b71824d8)`.  This is because an object in Perl is a reference, and normally it's a hash reference.  ...

Comment: @Henri_S  [cont'd]   2) Establised libraries normally take care of that, defining informative/useful stringifications.  What `qr` object produces is actually a valid pattern.  Try it: define some `qr` pattern, print it to a console, then copy that and paste it as a regex patter and it will do the same as the oriiginal `qr` pattern

Comment: @Henri_S  (I see now I missed a part of your comment, sorry for restating it)  That `(?^:...)` is a [particular "_extended pattern_"](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#(?%5Ealuimnsx:pattern))  (search for "_stringification of compiled regular expressions_")